# Using Navigator.pushReplacement with variable result property

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation

I am trying to pass a value to a Widget down the Navigator stack. Sample code:

```
class FirstPage extends StatefulWidget{
//...

receivedValue = await Navigator.push<String>(context, CupertinoPageRoute(
  (ctx) => SecondPage(),
));

}


class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget{
//...

receivedValue = await Navigator.pushReplacement<String,String>(context, CupertinoPageRoute(
  (ctx) => ThirdPage(),
));

}



class ThirdPage extends StatefulWidget{
//...
Navigator.pop<String>(context, outputString);
}
```

However the value is not passed to the first screen unless I keep the SecondPage in the stack. Reading [the docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pushReplacement.html), there is a `result` property in `pushReplacement` that passes back to the previous screen in the navigator stack. In case of the replacing screen is popped.

However, the value I want to pass depends on user input in `ThirdScreen`. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `pushReplacement`, you can just push the third page and pop the second page after the third page is popped!

```
class FirstPage extends StatefulWidget{
//...

receivedValue = await Navigator.push<String>(context, CupertinoPageRoute(
  (ctx) => SecondPage(),
));

}


class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget{
//...

receivedValue = await Navigator.push<String,String>(context, CupertinoPageRoute(
  (ctx) => ThirdPage(),
));

Navigator.pop(context, receivedValue);
}



class ThirdPage extends StatefulWidget{
//...
Navigator.pop<String>(context, outputString);
}
```

Comment: This is what I was doing, but the second page keeps rebuilding and calling the server anytime the third page triggers a change. The third page is a form, so the rebuilds happen constantly.

I don't know why it is happening, but it way outside the scope of my app and I don't need the page anyway.